# How would I tell if my array has reached the maximum size? [ActionScipt 2]

Tags: actionscript-2

I have a very long array that doesn't seem to load, how would I tell if it is too long? According to adobe, [the maximum size of a variable is 12 bytes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-movie-size-limit-flash.html) however I have previously been able to load arrays that are much larger than that. On another note, can you do something like this shrink the size of an array?

```
var LEFT = "com.games.Note.TYPE_LEFT";
var RIGHT = "com.games.Note.TYPE_RIGHT";
var songData = new Array(RIGHT,LEFT,RIGHT,LEFT,RIGHT,LEFT,RIGHT,LEFT)
```